# cocoon pass value to partial and fetch and reuse an already used nested object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, simple-form, nested-forms, cocoon-gem

I Have 2 models `Invoice` and `Payement` defined like this:

```
class Invoice < ApplicationRecord
 has_many :invoicings
 has_many :payements, through: invoicings
 accepts_nested_attributes_for: :payements
 attr_accessor :old_payement_number
 attr_accessor :payement_type
 enum payement_type: [ :new, :old ]
end

class Payement < ApplicationRecord
 has_many :invoicings
 has_many :invoices, through: :invoicings
end
```

I use Cocoon with simple form to create a nested forms and it works very fine, but i want to add something, i want add an additional field in the parent form with the accessor `old_payement_number` and `payement_type`, if the `payement_type` is set to new it will use a new subform, in other case it will fetch and old payement and add it to the subform with disabled to true.
i already have the form and partial for the nested form and i aldready used link_to_add_association like this:

```
= link_to_add_association 'add payement', f, :payements, render_options: { locals: {payement_type: 'new', old_payement_number: 'any number'}}
```

here my 3 questions:

1) how to pass a value inside a field to the nested form partial?

2) how to use locals passed to the partial to fetch old payement in the database and fill the subform with it?

3) it there a better way to implement what i want to do?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, then I am afraid you are a bit confused how cocoon works: everything is pre-rendered on the server. So you cannot change the `locals` hash at the time the button is clicked (the partial is already rendered!). What you _can_ do is use pure javascript and change the form before or after insert. Otherwise you will have to revert to use ajax/xhr and fetch the nested form from the server and render it using the changed locals.

Comment: yes you are right i feel bit confused and javascript is my achilles' heel, but if i understand what you are explaining to me, i must try something like that: give the link to association an id, and in javascript using eventlistener, every time the value of the input change, the value of the link to association locals must also change

Comment: @nathanvda i had another solution, since i don't have many payement type, i created a link to each type of payement and let only one to be visible using javascript, my ne question is if i can use somthing like seletize to reuse old payement and nested form to create nes ones,  can i use both in the same form?